# What are the prerequisites for "Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals (1938)" by Turing?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I skimmed through the paper, but it seemed to become increasingly difficult.
I'm a self learner and a math beginner.

Although I dabbled with linear algebra, calculus, and real analysis in university, I wasn't serious and didn't touch them for 6-7 years. So, I forgot almost everything. I recently finished “How to Prove It: A Structured Approach, 2nd Edition” by Daniel J. Velleman, and that's virtually all I know about math.

Can you compile an order of books and papers that I should read before I embark on reading "Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals (1938)" by Turing?

Comment: What is your logic background, by the way? Have you seen at least an outline on the incompleteness theorems?

Comment: “How to Prove It: A Structured Approach, 2nd Edition” by Daniel J. Velleman is essentially my only background. All I know about incompleteness theorem is that cyclic dependency between types is not ok and that a system can't be complete by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As prerequisites, you'll need a good background in mathematical logic, up to and including Gödel's incompleteness theorem(s); familiarity with basic set theory (in particular, ordinals!); and somewhat more than the basics of computability theory, but circa 1938. Probably, and fortunately, you can get the basics in one place: Mendelson's [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482237725) is a standard work that covers a lot of this material.

It will be helpful to have read about recursive ordinals and systems of ordinal notations as devised by Kleene. Hartley Roger's book [Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262680521) is a masterful presentation of the subject circa 1967, and contains much more than was known in 1938. In particular Rogers discusses recursive ordinals and hierarchies built using them.

For context, Church and his 1930s PhD students Turing and Kleene were, it's fair to say, the founders of computability theory (aka recursion theory).
Turing did his work on ordinal logic under Church at Princeton. The motivation of the study was to transcend the limitations of incompleteness, by using ordinals to ascend, in an "constructive" way, from a true but incomplete theory to larger, "less incomplete" theories.

Comment: Another book that might be helpful is Torkel Franzén's *Inexhaustibility*, which aims at explaining exactly this progression towards more "less incomplete" theories.

Comment: @Nagase *Inexhaustibility: A Non-Exhaustive Treatment* -- a great title. Thanks, I didn't know of the work. Judging from the table of contents, it seems to be self-contained, and brings the discussion up to the present (2004). Very apropos.

Comment: I'm not sure with which ones are essential and which ones are not.

Comment: @crocket What do you mean? Which books are essential for reading the paper? Which results? Which what is essential for what?

Comment: I was presented with multiple materials by multiple people. I'd like to reduce the amount of pages that I should read.

Comment: Try *Inexhaustibility*. I gave a link in an earlier comment to the "Look Inside!" reader on amazon, so you can do that & see if it's within reach.

Comment: Oops, the link vanished when I redid the comment to fix a typo... [here ya go](http://www.amazon.com/Inexhaustibility-Non-Exhaustive-Treatment-Lecture-Notes/dp/1568811756#reader_1568811756)